# A simple but challenging SQL Question, at least I couldn't find a way out except doing it externally (c#)

Tags: sql, sql-server, algorithm, t-sql

I have an SQL Table which consists of 1 column only

```
Column Name
A 
A
A
B
B
B
B
C
D
D
E
```

I need an SQL Code that returns the cut points. For the table above, it will return this:

```
Column Name
    3
    7
    8
    10
    11
```

3 is the end of A's and 7 is the end of B's and 8 is the end of C's and so on...

Let's see what can you come up with :=)

Comment: To start with, you need to order the results of the table (since they are not of a guaranteed order).

Comment: can you make it more clear please? I didn't get.

Comment: Technically the question is flawed because, by definition, SQL tables do not have any implied ordering, and therefore, do not have row numbers.

Comment: sql server 2000 and earlier or 2005 and later?

Comment: By the way I am using SQL server 2000

Comment: totally agree with randy miller

Comment: I don't understand how it is related with row numbers, So does Lieven's answer is not fully correct ? Or what do you think about Lieven's answer ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Assuming the data can be sorted on your `Column`, the plan is to generate a `row number` for each row and do a `group by` to retrieve your data points.

#### SQL Server 2000

```
DECLARE @YourTable TABLE (Col VARCHAR(1))
CREATE TABLE #TempTable (ID INTEGER IDENTITY(1, 1), Col VARCHAR(1))

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TempTable OFF
INSERT INTO @YourTable (Col) VALUES ('A')
INSERT INTO @YourTable (Col) VALUES ('A')
INSERT INTO @YourTable (Col) VALUES ('A')
INSERT INTO @YourTable (Col) VALUES ('B')
INSERT INTO @YourTable (Col) VALUES ('B')
INSERT INTO @YourTable (Col) VALUES ('B')
INSERT INTO @YourTable (Col) VALUES ('B')
INSERT INTO @YourTable (Col) VALUES ('C')
INSERT INTO @YourTable (Col) VALUES ('D')
INSERT INTO @YourTable (Col) VALUES ('D')
INSERT INTO @YourTable (Col) VALUES ('E')

INSERT INTO #TempTable
SELECT      *
FROM        @YourTable
ORDER BY    Col

SELECT    MAX(ID)
FROM      #TempTable
GROUP BY  Col

DROP TABLE #TempTable
```

#### SQL Server 2005

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Col VARCHAR(1))

INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('A')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('A')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('A')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('B')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('B')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('B')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('B')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('C')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('D')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('D')
INSERT INTO @Table VALUES ('E')


SELECT  MAX(RowNumber)
FROM    (SELECT RowNumber = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY Col), Col
         FROM   @Table) t
GROUP BY Col
```

Comment: Any solution for sql server 2000 ?

Comment: @stckvrflw - I've updated the answer to include a SQL Server 2000 solution.

Comment: Is this suppose to work when I copy paste it ? Because I get the following error: An explicit value for the identity column in table '@TempTable' can only be specified when a column list is used and IDENTITY_INSERT is ON.

Comment: Try specifying the column in the insert statements
INSERT INTO @YourTable(col) VALUES ('A')

Comment: <g> it was but I don't have a 2000 instance running so I tested with 2005. Simply add the column name to the inserts should suffice. I've updated the solution.

Comment: @stckvrflw - could you try the new version using #TempTable?

Comment: didn't work, also I used a version with SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TempTable ON, nothing changes.

Comment: I tried a few things, and simplified some parts of the code that doesn't give an error. Here is the error giving part.

SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TempTable ON
INSERT #TempTable
SELECT      *
FROM        @YourTable
ORDER BY    Col
SET IDENTITY_INSERT #TempTable OFF

Comment: Hello, I solved the problem, we forget to write (Col) while inserting into the temp table. Here how it should be. INSERT INTO TempTable (Col)
SELECT      *
FROM        @YourTable
ORDER BY    Col

Thanks for help Lieven :)

Comment: You'r welcome. Thanks for letting us know what solved it for you.

Answer (score 3):

```
with endings(columnname, ending) as
(
    select columnname, row_number() over (order by columnname) as 'ending'
    from theTable
)
select max(ending)
from endings
group by columnname
```

Answer (score 1):

Solution for Oracle:

Assuming the name of the column is COL1,

```
SELECT COL1,MAX(ROWNUM)
  FROM TEST_CHARS
 GROUP BY COL1
 ORDER BY COL1;
```